# Correct way to denote things in logical notation (with quantifiers)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, quantifiers

I am having trouble denoting things with quantifiers. For example, I'd like to define when a sequence is bounded from above. There is my definition:

> Sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from above if and only if there exists a real number $K$ for which for every positive integer $n$ the following holds: $ a_n \leq K$

I'll try to use less words and more symbols...

> Sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from above $ \iff \exists K \in \mathbb{R} \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus {0} \implies a_n \leq K $

But sometimes, I see things like this:

> Sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from above $ \iff \left( \exists K \in \mathbb{R} \right) \left( \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus {0} \right) \implies a_n \leq K $

I assume there is an "and" hidden between the parentheses.

What would be correct? I am confused.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you describe a sequence which is bounded from above. You need to write $a_n\geq K$.

Comment: Quite right, small mistake. Will correct it in a moment.

Comment: $∃K∈Rf⟹∀n∈Z∖0⟹an≤K$ is wrong. The existential quantifier is related to ''and'' and the all quantifier is related to implication. That is,$∃K∈R\wedge∀n∈Z∖0⟹an≤K $.

Comment: @Wuestenfux That means that the second denotion is the correct one. So if I am right, with another example, let's say the limit of the sequence, the denotion would be: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n) = L \iff \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R} \wedge N \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \wedge n > N \implies | a_n - L | < \varepsilon $. Am  I right?

Comment: Why do you allow negative indices? Is that one purpose?

Comment: Don't put $\implies$ between quantifiers and their dependent statement. Write either $(\exists K\in \Bbb R)(\forall n\in \Bbb N)a_n\le K$ [with bounded quantifiers] or $\exists K(K\in \Bbb R\land \forall n(n\in\Bbb N\to a_n\le K))$ [with unbounded quantifiers]; the need for parentheses or other interpunction may vary by local style. (I also wrote $\Bbb R$ for real numbers as I don't know what you mena with $R_f$, and $\Bbb N$ instead of \Bb bZ\setminus 0$ as I do not assume you index your sequences with non-zero integers (i.e., including negative ones)

Comment: Your requirement that $K$ must be an element of the sequence is wrong. For example, $n\mapsto 1-\frac1n$ is bounded from above, but there is no number _in its range_ that is an upper bound for it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, darn it... I'll fix that in a moment. But that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma *sigh* Fixed that too, sorry.

Comment: logic topics are followed by nitpickers, I suppose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't write the $\implies$ after the quantor.
The correct syntax is $\forall x : \phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is a correct statement. Ditto $\exists x: \phi(x)$

We also use $\forall x \in A: \phi(x)$ as a shortcut for
$\forall x:( (x \in A) \implies \phi(x))$ and $\exists x \in A: \phi(x)$ for 
$\exists x: ((x \in A) \land \phi(x))$
The $\implies$ stands between statements, so it's always used in ($\phi \implies \psi$)-like statements (with an antecedent and a consequent).

So if $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function,we can write $f$ is bounded above by

$$\exists K \in \mathbb{R}: (\forall x \in X: (f(x) \le K))$$ with some "superfluous" brackets (being a bit formal). As a real-valued sequence is just a function from $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the above applies to sequences as well, changing $X$ to $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(n)$ to $a_n$ if you prefer.

Comment: Small question: what do you mean by "quantor"? I should add that, if you reserve "quantifier" for the entity $\forall$ and use "quantor" for the entity $\forall(x \in \mathbb{R})$, I've been looking for terminology to express precisely this distinction for at least 6 months :)

Comment: @goblin I learnt "quantor" for the symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$. Might be a Dutch thing, though.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping there'd be a difference.

Comment: German agrees: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantor .Wikipedia uses the (ugly!) spelling kwantor for the Dutch variant.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Perhaps I will use "quantor" for $\forall$ and "quantifier" for $\forall(x \in \mathbb{R})$ from now on.

Comment: Formally only $\forall x$ is valid notation (in formal logic). $\forall (x \in A)$ is a notational shortcut, not a separate notion or syntactical element. At least for first order logic.

Comment: I agree completely, except that your sentence should be prefaced by the disclaimer "According to the standard viewpoint on such things..." If I get into the Master's program next semester, I'll finally get to write a thesis in which $\forall(x \in A)$ is perfectly formal, and it will denote a particular morphism in an appropriate category. Hopefully they let me in :)

Comment: Like I said, there is a difference between formal syntax (as done in logic) and informal notation, where "do I get the point across" is more important. But having used elementary submodels of ZFC etc. I tend to be careful about these things. I prefer putting the quantifiers into words in papers.

Comment: This is a bit too much for me... (I am preparing for a matura exam) But you are saying I can use a colon with the meaning of 'for which', right? At my school, the teacher used a simple (not double) arrow instead of the colon, as I remember. Is that accepted usage as well? By the way, quantifiers are called 'kvantorok' ~ 'quantors' in Hungarian as well.

Comment: Yes, the colon is fine,and standard. Don't use the arrow, it's confusing IMHO. An implication has 2 parts. Your teacher's notation was maybe a relic of the correct $\forall x: (x \in A) \implies \phi(x))$ for $\forall (x \in A) : \phi(x)$ shortcut?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Final question, how would you define the limit of a sequence? Is the following correct? A sequence $\{a_n\}$'s limit is the real number $L$ $\iff$ $ \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}: \left( \exists N \in \mathbb{R}: \left( n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \varepsilon \right) \right) $

Comment: Almost, as you need $\varepsilon > 0$ and an explicit quantifier for $n$: $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}: (\varepsilon > 0 ) \implies ((\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: ((\forall n : (n \in \mathbb{N} \land  n > N)  \implies (|a_n - L| \le \varepsilon))$

Comment: Or using shortcuts: $\forall \varepsilon>0: \exists N: \forall (n > N): |a_n - L| \le \varepsilon)$, where $\varepsilon$ is implicitly from the reals, and $n,N$ from the natural numbers, from context info.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Now I don't get it again... Why wasn't $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ enough? That also means that $\varepsilon$ is greater than $0$, doesn't it? This is too hard for me... Does this mean that for every $\varepsilon$, if it is greater than 0, then there is a natural # $N$, for which every $n$ that is natural and greater than $N$, which implies (I don't get *this part*) that etc. ?

Comment: I did not see the $\mathbb{R}^+$, sorry, then it's OK.So then $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall (n \in \mathbb{N}): (n > N) \implies |a_n - L| \le \varepsilon$ or  $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall (n > N): |a_n - L| \le \varepsilon$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60287/discussion-between-bertalanp99-and-henno-brandsma).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an implication in your statement hence you cannot write $\Rightarrow$ somewhere. An implication would be appropriate if your statement contains an 'if' in some form somewhere e.g.

> For all natural numbers a,b,c it holds that if a and b are greater or equal than c then the sum of a and b is already greater than c.
> $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq0}: (a \geq c \land b \geq c)\Rightarrow (a+b \geq c)$

If you know what you are talking about you can leave out the brackets.

I would write

> Let $R_f$ be $\dots$ . The sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from below if and only if
>
> $\exists K \in R_f : \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq0}: a_n \leq K$

You can read the colons as 'such that' or 'for which...'

If you are lazy you can also leave out the colons.

If you want to clarify that it is a definition or shorten your definition you can do this

> Sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from below $:\Leftrightarrow$ ...

or

> Sequence $\{ a_n \}$ is bounded from below $\stackrel{def}{\Leftrightarrow}$ ...

Comment: The correction notation for quantors is $\forall x (x\in A\Rightarrow P(x))$ and $\exists x(x\in A\wedge Q(x))$, where $P$ and $Q$ are predicates in $x$.